How to set up tmux themes properly on macOS terminal?
I tried to set up tmux with the macOS terminal by importing my .tmux.conf file from my Ubuntu 22.04 machine and the theme is not being applied properly. Regardless of what theme I choose, it displays as a plain black background and the colors of the status bar are not correct. I tried using kitty and iTerm2 and the same problem exists.
I tried adding
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"

to .tmux.conf file and it did not change anything. I am new to macOS and I don't know what I am missing.

Maybe post your config so we can see what you've tried?

I have my .tmux.conf as:
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix

# reload config file
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf


# Plugins:
set -g @plugin 'catppuccin/tmux#latest'
set -g @catppuccin_flavour 'mocha'

set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'

